# Selenium SendKeys not always working in Blazor app

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bootstrap-4, blazor

I have boostrap modal that I close with ESC button. It uses standard bootstrap 4 javascript (including jquery and popper).

Following Selenium code works localy but mostly fails in my CD pipeline and I don't know why.

It opens the modal dialog and then closes it using ESC key. Screenshots of failed test run confirms that the dialog was opened but never closed.

What could be causing the undeterministic behaviour?

```
    _aboutOrderModal.WaitUntilLoaded();
    Assert.IsTrue(_aboutOrderModal.RootElement.Displayed, "AboutOrderModal");
    _aboutOrderModal.Close(); //ThrowTimeoutException

public record AboutOrderModal(IWebDriver Driver, IWebElement RootElement)
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> FormValues => RootElement.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".form-value"));
    public void WaitUntilLoaded() 
    {
        Driver.WaitUntil(_ => RootElement.Displayed);
        Driver.WaitUntil(_ => FormValues.Count > 10);
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        RootElement.SendKeys(Keys.Escape);
        Driver.WaitUntil(_ => !RootElement.Displayed); // ThrowTimeoutException
    }
}
```

wait until is just a wrapper:

```
  public static TResult WaitUntil<TResult>(this IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, TResult> condition, int miliseconds = 3000)
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(miliseconds));
        return wait.Until(condition);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? Or is this just a silent failure?

Comment: try/catch your SendKeys call... I'm guessing you'll catch StaleElement there.  The "FindElements" call will return if at least one element is found.  You may also find an exception happening when RootElement.Displayed is called.   (somewhat random results usually point to timing issues for webdriver stuff...)

Comment: I get the timeout exception in my WebDriverWait.Until(condition), see comment in the code. RootElement.Displayed returns true, see the Assert.IsTrue,which passes. Also the screenshot after the failure shows the popup displayed